# Linear Equation as matrix

Tags: matrices, polynomials

Using a series of 3x3 matrices multiplied together, it is possible to create a matrix which will rotate, translate, scale and invert a size 2 vector.

Using a 4x4, it is possible to do this to a size 3 vector.

I am aware you can do it with a smaller sized matrix, but a n+1 allows for better multiplication.

Therefore, I assume I can create a series of 2x2 matrices which when multiplied together will perform a series of multiplications/additions of 1x1 matrix, or a number.

Therefore, can I represent any polynomial equation as a matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A polynomial does not transform like a matrix does. A polynomial will take $x$, and output $f(x)$. So if you mean to ask, "can there be a transformation matrix that takes $x$ into $f(x)$?" I'll say no. Matrix transformations are linear, and polynomials are not. Also, to multiply an $n \times n$ matrix by an $(n-1)$ vector is only possible under some restrictions. If you want to preserve the dimension of the vector, then you must add a final $0$ component to the vector and make sure the final transforming matrix has $0s$ in the $nth$ row and column to ensure that the vector's dimension is preserved. If you do not care about increasing the dimension of the vector, then no restrictions apply but your final vector will not transform under any of the physical transformations you thought you're using.